# Definition of h.c.f./g.c.d. not fitting with $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory

In my lecture notes, and also on many websites, the definition of the *highest common factor* of two elements in an integral domain $R$, say $a$ and $b$, is an element $c$ such that:

1. $c|a$ and $c|b$
2. $d|a$ and $d|b$ $\implies$ $d|c$

But when I think of an example, say the ring $\mathbb{Z}$, and take $a=14,b=28$, it is clear (from the simple integer definition) that $\mathrm{hcf}(14,28)$ is $7$.
However, here $2$ is also a common factor, but $2$ does *not* divide $7$.
So by the above definition, $7$ is not the highest common factor.

What am I missing here?
I am assuming I must be making some very very simple mistake, but can't spot it!

Comment: ${\rm gcd}(14,28) = 14,\,$ not $\,7.\,$ If $\,a\mid b\,$ then $\,c\mid a,b \iff \,c\mid a,\,$ so $\,\gcd(a,b) = a.$

Comment: Oh wow, can't believe I missed that one... that's embarrassing. Fancy posting as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Time Ok, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $\,\gcd(14,28) = 14,\,$ not $\,7.\,$ If $\,a\mid b\,$ then $\,c\mid a,b \iff \,c\mid a,\,$ so $\,\gcd(a,b) = a.\ \ $

**Remark** $\ $ The definition is written more naturally as

$$ c\mid a,b\iff c\mid\gcd(a,b)$$

since $(1)$ follows by specializing $\,c = \gcd(a,b)\,$ above.